Codeigniter 3 won't show in localhost
The output when I entered localhost/[folder_project_name]
For information, this folder I've got is the source code for my project. This source code given to me from the lead. I want to make similar laravel project from this old project that using old Codeigniter version 3.
And the previous database using mysql, now I want to take a peek by running this project through localhost for having full experience. And I've also set the config.php for connecting to the existing database I've imported to the localhost as well.
Cause I never held an Codeigniter projects before and only using Laravel as PHP Framework, I don't know what to do. I beg your kindness to answer my simple question.

Check your .htaccess file. It could be the reason. Turn on the development mode so if there is any errors then you can see it.

Check the PHP error log, and the apache log. And/or enable on-screen error reporting. A 500 error just means the code crashed. From that we, and you, cannot tell why it crashed, and therefore cannot fix it. You need to find the underlying error message before anyone can do anything. P.S. "500 Internal Server Error" is just a generic HTTP status code, it's not specific to CodeIgniter.

And the previous database using mysql, now I want to take a peek by running this project through localhost: php 500 errors most often result from a erroneous database connection, set ENVIRONMENT to 'development' (that's in the root index.php) and check your browser's network tab pressing F12. Most likely you'll find some mySQL errors
